# Is there a way to convert this MDX syntax to DAX?

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular, mdx-query

I'm changing a legacy multidimensional analysis services to tabular and "Converting" the `MDX` measures to `DAX`. (I don't have much knowledge using MDX)

I found the script below and i'm not sure what it is doing.

```
([Origin].[Origin].&[BUDGET FILE],[Measures].[Value])
```

I think it's is using the Column `Value` inside the Budget file located in the Origin to fill or create something in the measures.

So, first can anyone help me understand what this code is doing?
And second, would DAX support such thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the equivalent assuming the Value measure is a Sum.

```
CALCULATE(SUM(YourTableName[Value]), 'Origin'[Origin]="BUDGET FILE")
```